# How to attach focus handler to table cell (TD Element)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a rather simple problem.

With a table cell, how to I set a focus handler to it? The table cell (TD element) has a tabindex attribute set to zero and the element receives focus in the browser.

But, my event handler below is not firing. What gives?

Thank you.

```
$("td").on('focus', function () {
    $("#divContainerID").html($(this).html());
});
```

Comment: [Seems to fire](http://jsfiddle.net/9su1gfzu/). How've you detected the event is not firing?

Comment: The usual reason for this is that the element doesn't exist yet as of when you run your code above. Make sure that code is in a `script` tag *below* the HTML for the elements it's supposed to act on (just before the closing `</body>` tag is good). Or, second-best, use jQuery's `ready` callback. If loading the table cells dynamically, there's a question here about that.

Comment: Probably you create that table in a later timing?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ahh, that might explain it; I am using a DataTables plug in and perhaps the cell doesn't exist at the time this call is made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You run the handler at a certain moment. Later, you generate the `td` elements. But they were not existent when you defined the event. You need to find a selector, which already exists when you run the handler. In worst case it is `"body"` and you attach the handler inside a loader handler of `$(function() {});`

I will denote the selector you need as a `selector` variable, which is supposed to hold the right selector, pointing to a selection of tags, which already exists when you define the event and all the targeted `td` elements will be inside those:

```
$(selector).on('focus', "td", function () {
    $("#divContainerID").html($(this).html());
});
```

Note, that with the `.on()` I am using above selector is expected to describe all the elements holding current or future `td` elements where the event is desirable and the elements matching the selector must be already existent when you attach the event handler.

Comment: This was it; setting the order correctly on this handler fixed the issue.